# jQuery slider get last value

Tags: javascript, jquery, nouislider

```
var right = 2223;
var left = 9;

connectSlider.noUiSlider.on('change', function(){
  var values = connectSlider.noUiSlider.get();

console.log('changed');

});
```

Here I have event to handle slider value changes, when I drag slideR i see  for example 150 times "changed" how to write slider to handle only last value after change ?

Comment: I think your issue is that every value change is a change event. Does it provide any more events to hook into like stop dragging? You may be able to use a mouseup event as well.

Comment: Try to use `set` event. (But even with `change` everything should work)

Answer (score 1):

I see, you are using noUiSlider. There is a set event you can use.

http://refreshless.com/nouislider/events-callbacks/